# LEFT OUTER JOIN with four table

Tags: mysql, sql, t-sql, join, left-join

Here is the table structure

#### User table

```
Column  
fb_id   
email   
name    
fname   
lname   
gender  
fb_link 
created
```

#### referral table

```
Column
id  
referred_by 
joinee  
created
```

Currently implemented one SQL is (Example 1)

```
SELECT u.fb_id
    ,fb_link
    ,name
    ,r.referred_by
    ,u.created 
FROM users u 
LEFT OUTER JOIN referral r 
    ON u.fb_id=r.joinee
```

#### result of above query

```
joinee              referer
10152250261037651   NULL
10152604594389921   NULL
10154430845000507   1518673071699780
....
....
....
....
547146735389782     NULL
```

Here is the sql (Example 2)

```
SELECT u_joinee.fb_id joinee_fb_id
    ,u_referer.fb_id referer_fb_id
    ,u_joinee.NAME joinee_name
    ,u_referer.NAME referer_name
FROM users u_joinee
    ,users u_referer
    ,referral r_j
    ,referral r_r
WHERE u_referer.fb_id = r_r.referred_by
    AND u_joinee.fb_id = r_j.joinee
```

#### result of above query

```
joinee_fb_id        referer_fb_id       joinee_name referer_name
10154430845000507   1518673071699780    Saselsdein  Bsdasd
```

What I am looking out for is I need both name in `joinee_name` and `referer_name` in the output. But I ma not able to use four tables in `LEFT OUTER JOIN` clause like i did for example 1 I want to fetch both records which include both non referral and referral joinees Is there any way to expect required result as shown below

#### Expected result

```
joinee_fb_id        referer_fb_id       joinee_name referer_name
10154430845000507   1518673071699780    Saselsdein  Bsdasd
10154430845000347   Null                asd         NULL
10154430845000567   Null                asd asdm    NULL
10154230845000567   Null                Dsd asdm    NULL
10154330845000567   Null                sdm         NULL
101544553045000567  Null                Esd aedm    NULL
```

Comment: Why can't you use four tables in `LEFT OUTER JOIN`?

Comment: `FROM users u_joinee, users u_referer, referral r_j, referral r_r` is equivalent to `FROM users u_joinee CROSS JOIN users u_referer CROSS JOIN referral r_j CROSS JOIN referral r_r`. You need to replace each of those `,` operators with an `INNER` or `OUTER` join.

Comment: @Barmar because I am using same table twice `users u_joinee, users u_referer, referral r_j, referral r_r`  check users table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can join with the `users` table twice by giving it different aliases, just like you do with your implicit inner join.

I don't think you need to join with `referral` twice. A single row in the `referral` table links a referrer and a joinee.

```
SELECT u_joinee.fb_id joinee_fb_id ,u_referer.fb_id referer_fb_id, u_joinee.name joinee_name, u_referer.name referer_name
FROM users AS u_joinee
LEFT JOIN referral AS r ON r.joinee = u_joinee.fb_id
LEFT JOIN users AS u_referer ON r.referred_by = u_referer.fb_id
```

Comment: thanks a lot for the help .. here is one update you need to make in your ans remove the unwanted underscore (`u_joinee_.fb_id`)  that generate invalid column error